# finding the row with earliest date for each customerID who purchased specific product and return the date in new column

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, top-n

I'm working with PowerBI and have the following table:

```
customer_id|item_id| date    
1          |   A   | 01/01/01        
1          |   B   | 01/01/01        
1          |   A   | 02/02/02        
1          |   A   | 03/03/03        
2          |   A   | 03/03/03        
2          |   C   | 03/03/03        
...
```

I would like to find the earliest date for each `customer_id` who purchased item A and return 1 in a new column. So that I get a new column in the table that looks like the following:

```
customer_id | item_id | date     | Column_want 
1           |   A     | 01/01/01 | 1
1           |   B     | 01/01/01 | blank
1           |   A     | 02/02/02 | blank
1           |   A     | 03/03/03 | blank
2           |   A     | 03/03/03 | 1
2           |   C     | 03/03/03 | blank
...
```

I've tried to filter the column by item A and then using `TOPN(1,...)` to choose only the top rows. However, it doesn't seem to work.

This seems like such a trivial request. Is there any smarter way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use `TOPN` for this but that function returns an entire row of a table so it looks pretty clunky like this:

```
Column_want = 
IF (
    Table1[item_id] = "A" && Table1[date]
        = SELECTCOLUMNS (
            TOPN (
                1,
                FILTER (
                    Table1,
                    Table1[item_id] = "A"
                        && Table1[customer_id] = EARLIER ( Table1[customer_id] )
                ),
                Table1[date], ASC
            ),
            "date", Table1[date]
        ),
    1
)
```

I'd suggest something more like this:

```
Column_Want = 
IF (
    Table1[date]
        = CALCULATE (
            MIN ( Table1[date] ),
            FILTER (
                ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[customer_id], Table1[item_id] ),
                Table1[item_id] = "A"
            )
        ),
    1
)
```

Or this:

```
Column_Want =
IF (
    Table1[date]
        = MINX (
            FILTER (
                Table1,
                EARLIER ( Table1[item_id] ) = "A"
                    && Table1[customer_id] = EARLIER ( Table1[customer_id] )
            ),
            Table1[date]
        ),
    1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a calculated column using variables:

```
    Column_want = 
            VAR Customer_id ='Table'[customer_id]
            VAR Earliest_date = CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[date]),
                                   FILTER('Table','Table'[customer_id]=Customer_id))
            VAR Earliest_item = CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[item_id]),
                                   FILTER('Table','Table'[date]=Earliest_date),
                                   FILTER('Table','Table'[customer_id]=Customer_id))
    RETURN IF('Table'[date]=Earliest_date && 'Table'[item_id]=Earliest_item,
               1,BLANK())
```

The idea is to calculate the earliest date for a particular Customer ID using Calculate and max (Earliest_date variable). Earliest_Item variable is calculated to avoid multiple records for the same customer getting tagged as 1. Hope this helps.